# PostgreSQL counting from a special date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sum

i have the following code,

```
SELECT      
    years_month_count.day_date,
    years_month_count.year_date,
    years_month_count.month_date,
    years_month_count.no_of_customers_day,
    sum(years_month_count.no_of_customers_day) OVER (PARTITION BY year_date ORDER BY day_date) AS no_of_customers_ytd
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATE(date) as day_date,
        DATE_PART('year',date) as year_date,
        DATE_PART('month',date) as month_date,
        count(prepare_first_buyer.person_id) as no_of_customers_day
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            DATE(bestelldatum),
            person_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY person_id)
        FROM ani.bestellung
    ) prepare_first_buyer
    WHERE row_number=1
    GROUP BY DATE(date), DATE_PART('year',date),DATE_PART('month',date)
    ORDER BY DATE(date), DATE_PART('year',date),DATE_PART('month',date)
) years_month_count
```

the Output looks like this:

| day_date | year_date | month_date | no_of_customers_day | no_of_Customers_ytd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-04-04 | 2017 | 4 | 6 | 6 |
| 2017-04-05 | 2017 | 4 | 4 | 10 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

and so on.

The no_of_customers_ytd will be set to zero at the beginning of every new year (1.January).
But what i need is to set it to zero on a special date, lets say 1.June every year.
So i need a sum from everything between the 1.June till 30.March for every Year.

Thx for the help.

Comment: Please provide table descriptions (DDL) and sample data as text - **no images** ( or a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)) and the expected output of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=32b4eccdac9ca87dd685811adeefa8f1)

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY                             -- 4
        date_part('year',                                     -- 3
            the_date - interval '5 months'                    -- 2
        )     
    )
FROM t
WHERE date_part('month', the_date)::int NOT BETWEEN 4 AND 5   -- 1
```

1. Filter all dates you are not requiring. In your example all dates with months `4` and `5`
2. Shift your date range start to the beginning of the year. In your example you have to shift: `year-06-01` to `year-01-01`, so you need to subtract `5 months`. Because your date range never exceeds a year, all your relevant data now has the same year, which makes a great group criterion
3. Extract the `year` part to use it as group/partition criterion
4. Do your calculation on this criterion

Comment: Thx for the help and the explicit answer. But i dont understand 2 things. The 1. why do i not require those months? And the_date how is this defined?

Comment: 1. Your requirement was June until March. So you don't need April and May. Of course you can adjust the filter to your actual requirements 2. As you can see in the provided fiddle, the_date represents the date column

Comment: @hahakomisch thanks for accepting. Please upvote as well, I'd appreciate :)